# python3 unotools connection error failed to connect

Tags: python, python-3.x, connection, libreoffice-writer

I have searched for an answer, but nothing has helped so far. I have a method that I want to use to create an odt file and fill it with text. I also want the user to view the file when it is created. I am using python 3.4.3 unotools 0.3.3 LinuxMint 17.1 LibreOffice 4.2.8.2

The issue:

```
unotools.errors.ConnectionError: failed to connect: ('socket,host=localhost,port=8100', {})
```

The unotools sample worked fine from terminal - created and saved a sample.odt without errors. My draft code:

```
def writer_report(self):
    subprocess.Popen(["soffice", "--accept='socket,host=localhost,port=8100;urp;StarOffice.Service'"])
    time.sleep(5)  # using this to give time for LibreOffice to open - temporary
    context = connect(Socket('localhost', '8100'))
    writer = Writer(context)
    writer.set_string_to_end('world\n')
    writer.set_string_to_start('hello\n')
    writer.store_to_url('output.odt','FilterName','writer8')
    writer.close(True)
```

The LibreOffice application opens and remains open. However, the connection seem to be lost.
I hope someone can give me assistance, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I do not recommend code like this:

```
subprocess.Popen(...)
time.sleep(...)
```

It is better to use a shell script to start `soffice` and then call the python script.

However if you are determined to run `soffice` in a subprocess, then I recommend increasing the sleep time to at least 15 seconds.

See https://forum.openoffice.org/en/forum/viewtopic.php?t=1014.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I tried extending the time but still no joy.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the advice. I did want this run a a subprocess. I tried extending the time but still no joy.
I am now looking at using the Python odfpy 1.3.3 package which after beginning to use for a day  or two, I already am having more success with.